# volttron host a web page for dashboard

Tags: web-development-server, volttron

In the VOLTTRON readthedocs for the [Simple Web Agent Walk-through](https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/developing-volttron/developing-agents/example-agents/simple-web-agent-walk-through.html), is it possible to run a web agent on a stand alone VOLTTRON deployment? Or does a web agent need to be connected to a central Volttron instance? Can a VOLTTRON edge device connected to a central instance host a web interface?

What I am curious about is if a local edge device (central, not central, or mix) host a simple dashboard for agent setpoint control.

I am just playing around with some very simple html `<input>: The Input (Form Input) element` I was curious if best practice would be to host a seperate web instance where VOLTTRON could just hit a rest end point to get some "setpoint information" from the building operator staff, or if the edge device could just host a web interface itself..?

Very simple dashboard that I could maybe butter up with some javascript in browser later on, this is a rough idea I was curious about.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Slipstreaminc GEB</title>
        <style>
            label {
                display: block;
                font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
            }

            input,
            label {
                margin: .4rem 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Useful Links Below</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://192.168.0.105:5000/">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://192.168.0.105:5000/verify-event">LAST EVENT UPLOAD</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://192.168.0.105:5000/verify-load-roller">VERIFY LOAD ROLLER</a></li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <fieldset>
            <h1>Setpoints for buildling load rolling algorithm</h1>
            <form class="" action="index.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label>Building kW Setpoint:</label>
                <input type="number" name="" value=""><br>


              <legend>Weekdays Load Rolling Enabled Check Box:</legend>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="coding" name="interest" value="coding">
                <label for="coding"></label>
              </div>
              <legend>Weekends Load Rolling Enabled Check Box:</legend>
              <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="coding" name="interest" value="coding">
                <label for="coding"></label>
              </div>
            <hr>
                <label for="appt">Choose start time for electrical load rolling:</label>
                <input type="time" id="appt" name="appt"
                        min="09:00" max="21:00" required>
                <small>Available hours to select 9am to 9pm</small>
            <hr>
            <label for="appt">Choose end time for electrical load rolling:</label>
            <input type="time" id="appt" name="appt"
                   min="09:00" max="21:00" required>
            <small>Available hours to select 9am to 9pm</small>
        </fieldset>
        <form action="/transform" method="post" enctype="">
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Looks like this, thanks for any advice not a lot of wisdom here :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One **does not** need to have the volttron-central agent installed on a platform for an agent to server web content.

One **does** have to have a bind-web-address in the VOLTTRON configuration file for the specific instance.  A VOLTTRON agent must register with the instance running the web in order for the agent to handle callbacks for the web requests and establish the endpoints for requests.

One **does not** need to have volttron-central agent in order to have the ability to have admin access to the VOLTTRON instance.

What you have here can definitely be run on an edge device.  I would make sure you understand and have certificates for the edge devices if you are making them go through the internet however.

Comment: Cool thanks Craig, maybe future training YouTube video on how to make a dashboard for  single machine deployment for an edge device on TLS with certs? Nothing on the web only local area LAN type dashboard : )